# App for reading a downloaded ebook, with rotary dial to jump to a page

Tags: ebooks, bookmark, accessibility, books

There are several ebook contents out there but I find the apps that are currently available to read them a bit poor.

Forevermore, I often cannot choose which app to use when browsing a book (especially when I use an app from a book subscriber site such as O'Reilly Media (bookshelf)).

I am looking for an ebook reader that implements a rotary dial widget which is semitransparent and flips the book as you dial.

For instance, if a book has pages in the hundreds of pages, the outer rotary dial will list numbers say 0...3, inside it another rotary with numbers 0...9, and inside it yet another rotary with numbers 0...9.

To pick a page, you highlight by dragging the three corresponding dials in the concentric rotary dials widget.

As you drag and select on all dials, you can see the page in the background, and scroll it up/down, or dismiss the dials to read it.

Of course, the widget to bookmark any given page will not be missing.

Has anyone implemented such an ebook reader?

Such a reader would be quick to use and user friendly, as the user could quickly browse the book and see if the non contained what they were looking for at the right page and skip without missing out on the content while skipping.

Where can I find it?

Thanks.

Comment: What format are most of your ebooks? PDF? Also, would you have a screenshot of a similar dial in any other app?

Comment: Also, what operating system?